# SKLearn & ElasticNet: Cross validation fails when using Accuracy as a metric

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, elasticnet

I have a binary classification problem. I've been using `cross validation` to optimize the `ElasticNet` parameters. However ElasticNet only seems to work when I supply `roc_auc` as the scoring method to be used during CV, However I also want to test out a wide range of scoring methods, in particular `accuracy`. Specifically, when using accuracy, ElasticNet returns this error:

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets
```

However my `y` targets are indeed binary. Below is a replication of my problem using the dataset from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data?resource=download):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV, StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, recall_score, accuracy_score, precision_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet

data = pd.read_csv('data 2.csv')
# by default majority class (benign) will be negative
lb = LabelBinarizer()
data['diagnosis'] = lb.fit_transform(data['diagnosis'].values)
targets = data['diagnosis']
data.drop(['id', 'diagnosis', 'Unnamed: 32'], axis=1, inplace=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, targets, stratify=targets)

#elastic net logistic regression
lr = ElasticNet(max_iter=2000)
scorer = 'accuracy'
param_grid = {
    'alpha': [1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10],
    'l1_ratio': np.arange(0.2, 0.9, 0.1)
}
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
clf = GridSearchCV(lr, param_grid, scoring=scorer, cv=skf, return_train_score=True,
                    n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values)
```

I figured that ElasticNet might be trying to solve a linear regression problem so I tried  `lr = LogisticRegression(penalty='elasticnet', l1_ratios=[0.1, 0.5, 0.9], solver='saga')` as the classifier but the same problem persists.

If I use as the scoring metric `scorer = 'roc_auc'` then the model is built as expected.

Also, as a sanity to check to see if there is something wrong with the data I tried the same but with a random forest classifier and here the problem disappears:

```py
# random forest
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
param_grid = {
    'min_samples_split': [3, 5, 10],
    'n_estimators' : [100, 300],
    'max_depth': [3, 5, 15, 25],
    'max_features': [3, 5, 10, 20]
}
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
scorer = 'accuracy'
grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, scoring=scorer,
                        cv=skf, return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)
grid_search.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values)
```

Has anyone got any ideas on what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ElasticNet`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html) is a regression model.

If you want an `ElasticNet` penalty in classification, use [`LogisticRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html):

```py
lr = LogisticRegression(solver="saga", penalty="elasticnet")
```

---

**Minimal Reproducible Example**:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV, StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y)

lr = LogisticRegression(solver="saga", penalty="elasticnet", max_iter=2000)

param_grid = {
    'l1_ratio': np.arange(0.2, 0.9, 0.1)
}

clf = GridSearchCV(lr, param_grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10), return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried that, (as I highlighted in my question) but the same problem persists.

Comment: There's something wrong with your data then. I've edited this answer to include a full MRE.

Comment: Sorry but that can't be. The model works with RF, and actually this a replication of my problem on a second dataset (the one linked), on my own personal dataset the problem also persists. The full data and code is here linked if you wanna try and solve it for me :)

Comment: how come you didn't import accuracy like: `from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score` ?

Comment: This answer does not call `accuracy_score`, so it is not needed.

Comment: ok, looks like I spoke too soon. Your solution does indeed work Thanks! Two questions if you don't mind. where does your `accuracy` come from? Is it not a SKLearn metric? And second, how can I also pass a list of alpha parameters for the penalization severity?

Comment: Sure. (1) accuracy is calculated internally with `GridSearchCV` when `scoring='accuracy'` gets passed. You could also pass a callable (like `accuracy_score`), but it's not necessary unless you're customizing behavior.

Comment: (2) The `alpha` parameter is used for other combinations of solvers/penalties. For `elasticnet` penalty, the `l1_ratio` between `0.0` and `1.0` controls the ratio between L1 and L2.

Comment: (I *think* `alpha` is comparable with `C` for logistic regression, but double check the documentation).

Comment: Thanks. By the way your solution works but is taking forever to run. Weird that the ElasticNet behaves exactly like a binary classifier when I use auc_roc as the metric.

Comment: I'm glad things are working, grid search can take a while though. The `auc_roc` case is mostly a coincidence. ROC methods come out of signal detection theory, which use a continuously-distributed prediction vector and a binary target. ElasticNet produced continuous predictions, which is why it worked. (It's a huge side note, but I have some [in-progress work on ROC methods](https://github.com/aucroc/auc-calculator) if you want to skim some code while you wait for grid search to finish).